# ODE problem with power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing the homework assignment and I am having trouble because I don't know how to start on one problem.

The question is "Use the power series method to solve the given initial-value problem $$(x^2+5)''+y=0,\qquad  y(0)=0,\;\; y'(0)=2$$

You must show at least 5 nonzero terms of the power series)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $y = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots$, what is $y''$?  What is $(x^2+5) y'' + y$?